# Bash file working on local computer but not working on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2

I have a simple bash file which fixes the `npm` permission on my system. It goes like this

```
npm=`npm config get prefix`
echo "$npm"

if [[ $npm = "/usr/local" ]]
    then
    echo "Yes it's /usr/local"
    echo $npm/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
    sudo chown -R $(whoami) $npm/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
    echo "Complete"
elif [[ $npm = "/usr" ]]
    then
    echo "Uhhohh it's /usr gotta use a different method"
    mkdir ~/.npm-global
    npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
    export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
    source ~/.profile
    echo "No"
fi

npm install -g forever
npm install -g pm2
npm install -g bower
```

This works fine on my machine. But not my amazon ex2 instance. I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my AWS EC2 instance and Ubuntu 15.04 on my local system. The error which I get is `npm-permission.sh: line 2: =/usr: No such file or directory`

Which is the second line. What is the issue? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Try this as first line: `npm=$(npm config get prefix)`

Comment: Side note: $npm seems to be empty. You should change your if-clauses to `if [[ "$npm" = "/..." ]]` in order not to fail in this case.

Comment: @Cyrus this worked... Can you put that as an answer? So that I can mark it.

Comment: @Cyrus probably an explanation as well as to why that worked and why my older approached failed on my EC2 instance but worked on my local machine

Comment: I can only speculate. Perhaps it is an incomplete implementation of bash.

Comment: That error message wouldn't come from anything in the code you posted; I suspect it comes from `~/.profile`, and you have something like `$npm=/usr` (no quotes, no spaces around `=`) in a context where a file is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a change as suggested by @Cyrus in the comments I modified the script to have if [[ $npm = '' ]] which made it work. Here is the working script.

```
npm=$(npm config get prefix)
echo "$npm"

if [[ $npm = "/usr/local" ]]
    then
    echo "Yes it's /usr/local"
    echo $npm/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
    sudo chown -R $(whoami) $npm/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
    echo "Complete"
elif [[ $npm = "/usr" ]]
    then
    echo "Uhhohh it's /usr gotta use a different method"
    mkdir ~/.npm-global
    npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
    echo "export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
    source ~/.profile
    echo "No"
fi
```

I still don't know how it works, but it does. Some bash expert might throw some light on it.